# Open source auction project

Tags: c#, php, ruby, open-source

The project i'm taking a part needs some simple auction functionality. The basic concept is:

- There is list of products of two
  types: fixed cost and auction.
- Registered users can buy the fixed
  cost product or bid for auction product.
- The list of all products is
  predefined by admin (5 fixed costs, 5
  auctions).

So it looks like simple auction or shopping cart with auction functionality. I don't care about the platform (but prefer php/lamp, ruby/ror, .net or java). Does anybody know any good open source solution which fits to my needs i described?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=auction+script

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Auction Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636077/php-auction-script)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to look through the usual open source directories:

- http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&type_of_search=soft&words=auction
- http://www.opensourcescripts.com/dir/PHP/Auctions/
- http://freshmeat.net/search?q=auction&submit=Search
- http://www.hotscripts.com/search/all/auction+site

So there are a few. But if you depend on specific features (the last one is kind of too restrictive for a generic implementation), you won't get around adapting the code anyway.